# Equations with only text in them

Tags: equations

I would like to include equations in my article which have only text in them (in some cases there may be a little math) so that it keeps proper formatting. I tried using \mbox but then the text is so big that it is going out of the line. How do I include text in this way so that all formatting is preserved.

> ```
> \begin{equation}\label{key}
> The product of two complex numbers is given by the vector whose angle is the sum of the angles of the two complex numbers and whose magnitude is the product of the magnitudes of the
>  \end{equation}
> ```

Thanks

Comment: `\text{}` from `amsmath`

Comment: Providing an example of what you are looking for would be helpful.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I have added the same.

Comment: Please always make your code sections _complete_ documents, so that people can run them to see the result (see the code in the answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `\text{}`-command with `amsmath`-package or `\parbox{width}{text}` To get a newline.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}\label{key}
   \parbox{0.9\textwidth}{The product of two complex numbers is given by the vector whose angle is the sum of the angles of the two complex numbers and whose magnitude is the product of the magnitudes of the}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\text` is useless.

Comment: @greg Unnecessary would be more accurate:) Certainly, `\text` is useful with shorter bits of text.

Comment: @Andrew -- in this case, `\text` *is* useless, because among other things, it's supposed to "follow" the size and style of the surrounding text.  `\parbox` disables/overrides both those goals.  size isn't a problem here, but if the equation is in a theorem, chances are the text should appear in italic, and that *would* be a problem that would have to be addressed manually.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I agree...I was partly being pedantic (egreg's comment is unqualified) and partly trying to be funny (my humour is often not appreciated:)