# Equations with text and math interpersed

Tags: equations

This is related to the question I asked here:

[Equations with only text in them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192495/equations-with-only-text-in-them)

Basically I want to have an equation with a lot of text and some math in them. I don't want to use `\mbox` because there is a lot of text and it may start going out of the line. In the linked question a solution is provided using `\parbox` but I want to use math also in the middle.

For example:

```
\begin{equation}\label{key}
  The product of two complex numbers z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C} is given by the vector whose
  angle is the sum of the angles of the two complex numbers, 
  i.e. arz(z_1z_2)=arg(z_1)+arg(z_2) and whose magnitude is the product of the          
  magnitudes of the two complex numbers, i.e. |z_1z_2|=|z_1||z_2|
\end{equation}
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Wouldn't a theorem-like definition environment be more appropriate than an `equation` environment, here? (Hint: yes)

Comment: @Jubobs: How do I do that?

Comment: @Jubobs: Can numbering be accomplished in such an environment in a manner similar to equations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you can do this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}   %%% habitual addition
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{\widthof{(99)}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}\label{key}
    \left.\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\mylen\relax}
            The product of two complex numbers $z_1$, $z_2\in\mathbb{C}$ is given by the vector whose
            angle is the sum of the angles of the two complex numbers,
            i.e. $\arg(z_1z_2)=\arg(z_1)+\arg(z_2)$ and whose magnitude is the product of the
            magnitudes of the two complex numbers, i.e. $|z_1z_2|=|z_1||z_2|$
          \end{minipage}
    \right\}
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The same can be done with `\parbox` too.

Answer (score 7):

The "equation" in question contains not one but *two* entities that many people would interpret to be equations; moreover, both the text and the equations are very important. I therefore think you (and likely your paper's readers as well) would be better off if you chose a theorem-like environment to typeset the material, rather than insist on it being "just an equation".

This environment -- let's call it **Statement** for the sake of specificity -- can be cross-referenced easily. If you wish, you can use the `equation` counter to number the `statement` environments. An example of this usage is given below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,ntheorem}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref} % for "clever" cross-references
\theorembodyfont{\upshape} % choose \itshape if you prefer
\newtheorem{statement}[equation]{Statement}
\begin{document}
An equation:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:pyth}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

\begin{statement}\label{complex-prod}
The product of two complex numbers $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$ is given by the vector whose
  angle is the sum of the angles of the two complex numbers, 
  i.e.\ $\arg(z_1z_2)=\arg(z_1)+\arg(z_2)$ and whose magnitude is the product of the          
  magnitudes of the two complex numbers, i.e.\ $|z_1z_2|=|z_1||z_2|$.
\end{statement}

Another equation:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:euler}
\exp(i\pi)-1=0
\end{equation}

As was shown in \cref{eq:euler,complex-prod,eq:pyth}, \ldots

\end{document}
```