# Number quote environment like an equation

Tags: equations, numbering, quoting

I want to put an equation number to the right of a quote (the environment) as if it was an equation.  I have looked at [Equations with only text in them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192495), [How can I make LaTeX number my quotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50924) and [How do I label text with equation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114113).  So far I have this MWE but it is not exactly what i'm looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand\IdeaOne[1]{%
  \begin{equation}\parbox{.85\textwidth}{#1}\end{equation}}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{IdeaTwo}{%
  \list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
  \let\orig@item\item
  \def\item{
\orig@item[]\refstepcounter{equation}
\def\item{\hfill(\theequation)\orig@item[]\refstepcounter{equation}}}}
  {\hfill(\theequation)\endlist}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Normal text, quote and equation}
\blindtext\begin{quote}\blindtext\end{quote}\begin{equation}E=mc^2\end{equation}
\section{IdeaOne}
\IdeaOne{\blindtext}
\section{IdeaTwo}
\begin{IdeaTwo}
  \blindtext
\end{IdeaTwo}
\end{document}
```

The IdeaOne is pretty close but not exactly and I have to specify the size of the parbox manually.  IdeaTwo gets the margins right but does not put the equation number like I want it.  Does anyone know how to fix either of the two ideas?

I want to do this for a philosoohy text where some text is important and will be refered to like an equation in math text but the text is longer than one line (else I could use `\begin{equation}\text{...}\end{equation}`.  Maybe somebody has some idea for a different approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that these numbered quote environments are at the top level and not nested in other list environments, you can exploit the fact that, unless your equation numbers are too wide, they will fit in the available white space; in case they are wider for fitting, you should redefine `quote` in the first place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newsavebox\ideabox
\newenvironment{idea}
  {\begin{equation}
   \begin{lrbox}{\ideabox}
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\leftmargini}
   \setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}%
   \begin{quote}}
  {\end{quote}
   \end{minipage}
   \end{lrbox}\makebox[0pt]{\usebox{\ideabox}}
   \end{equation}}

\begin{document}
\begin{quote}\blindtext\end{quote}\begin{equation}E=mc^2\end{equation}

\begin{idea}
  \blindtext
\end{idea}
\end{document}
```

The “equationed” quote is typeset in a zero width box, so the equation number will not force a shift to the left.

[image]

Comment: Sadly I found a problem with this solution: Try `\blindtext\begin{idea}\blindtext\end{idea}\blindtext` to see that the vertical space around the `idea` is messed up (much smaler than with `\blindtext\begin{quote}\blindtext\end{quote}\blindtext` or `\blindtext\begin{equation}\parbox{\whatever}{\blindtext}\end{equation}\blindtext`).

Comment: @lucas You shouldn't do `\par` before `idea` and `\blindtext` adds a final par.

Comment: May I ask why "the equation number forces a shift to the left" if "The 'equationed' quote is not typeset in a zero width box"?

Comment: @TheGreatSeo Well, try it! ;-)

Comment: @egreg I tried but I wonder why. Or can you recommend keywords related to the phenomenon?

Comment: @TheGreatSeo That depends on how TeX computes the space to leave for the equation number. There are other methods, but we're doing something that would fit at natural width, so there's no need to go deeper.