# Multiple lines of text in math mode

Tags: math-mode, align

One of the assumptions in my paper requires a long line of text. Is there a way to format this nicely? I'd like to keep it in math mode so that it looks the same as the other assumptions and I can refer to it with a label.

Thanks!

```
\begin{align*}
\text{The joint distribution of $(D, M_1, M_2, \theta)$ admits a bounded density with respect to the product measure of the counting measure on the set $\{0,1\}$ and the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal{M}_1 \times \mathcal{M}_2  \times \Theta$. All marginal and conditional densities are also bounded.} \tag{A1}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204091/number-quote-environment-like-an-equation help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single line equations should never be in `align` (even without the `\text` requirement).

You could use

```
\begin{equation}
\parbox{.7\textwidth}{The joint distribution of $(D, M_1, M_2, \theta)$ admits a bounded
 density with respect to the product measure of the counting measure on the set
 $\{0,1\}$ and the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal{M}_1 \times \mathcal{M}_2
  \times \Theta$. All marginal and conditional densities are also bounded.}
 \tag{A1}
\end{equation}
```

Although probably I'd look at using an environment defined with `\newthorem` rather than math mode for this.